# Сколько не называй или сколько ни называй?

Tags: не-или-ни

Всё время путаюсь в не-ни. Вопрос: Сколько не называй или сколько ни называй? Мне больше нравится первый вариант, а на правильный больше похож второй.

Answer (score 4):

Конечно, "сколько ни называй". Здесь пишется усилительная частица "ни" согласно элементарной логике (много раз называй)и правилу о частице "ни" в придаточных уступительных

Answer (score 0):

"Ни" конечно. "Не" - отрицает. Проверить легко)

Answer (score 0):

Эта тема не так проста, так как встречаются парные варианты, например:

а) Сколько ни назовешь городов, я назову больше - СПП с придаточным уступительным, усилительная частица НИ относится к союзному слову СКОЛЬКО, нет отрицания, но есть усиление утвердительного значения.

б) Я назову столько городов, сколько ты не назовешь - СПП с придаточным определительным, НЕ - отрицательная частица, относится к глаголу.